# Issue animating fixed button with JQuery on Firefox

Tags: jquery, css, firefox, semantic-ui

I have a problem with JQuery .animate(), Firefox 30.0 and "position: fixed" CSS rule. I use Semantic UI framework to create the button and I would like the button was fixed in left top corner. I have even a sidebar that is shown and hidden if button is pressed. This is my code:

**CSS**

```
.ui.black.button.toggle{
position: fixed;
left: 0px;
top: 35px;
z-index: 99999;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="it">
<head>
    <!-- Standard Meta -->
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Site Properities -->
    <title></title>
    <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/cupertino/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.css" type="text/css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/semantic.min.css" type="text/css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css"/>
    <!-- PHP functions -->
    <?php require_once 'functions/functions.php'; ?>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Sidebar Part -->
    <?php include_once 'sidebar.php'; ?>
    <div class="ui black launch right attached button toggle">
        <i class="icon list layout"></i>
        <span class="text">Menu</span>
    </div>
    <div class="main container">
        <div class="ui form">
            <div class="ui four column page grid">
                <div class="column">
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                </div>
            </div>  
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- JS Framework -->
    <script src="js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="javascript/semantic.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- My JS -->
    <script src='javascript/main-script.js' type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**JQuery**

```
var sidebarStatus = 0;
$(document).on('click', '.ui.button.toggle', function() { 
    if(sidebarStatus === 0){
        sidebarStatus = 1;
        $(".ui.button.toggle")
                        .stop()
                        .animate({
                            "left" : "276px"
                        }, 'fast', function() {
                        });
    } else if(sidebarStatus === 1){
        sidebarStatus = 0;
        $(".ui.button.toggle")
                        .stop()
                        .animate({
                            "left" : "0px"
                        }, 'fast', function() {
                        });
    }
});
```

All works great on Safari and Chrome, but in Firefox 30.0 the button moves left randomly from 35px to 60px but never for the setted value (276px) in the .animate() function. However if I remove "position : fixed" from CSS also in Firefox works properly.
I have used even the onShow() and onHide() settings from Semantic UI framework but the result doesn't change. This issue makes me crazy!!! 
Someone can help me?

Thank you so much!!!

[image: Firefox with Sidebar hidden]
[image: Firefox with Sidebar]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for my issue. If I remove the animation script and use "margin-left" instead of "left" in CSS seems that the sidebar automatically and correctly pushes the button on the left. So this is my new CSS and JQuery code that works on Safari, Firefox and Chrome (HTML is the same):

**CSS**

```
.ui.black.button.toggle{
position: fixed;
margin-left: -8px;
margin-top: 35px;
z-index: 500;
}
```

**JQuery - SemanticUI**

```
$('.demo.sidebar')
        .sidebar({overlay: false, useCSS: false, onShow: function() {                    
            }, onHide: function() {
            }
        });
```

It works even without using Semantic UI settings:

**CSS**

```
.ui.black.button.toggle{
position: fixed;
margin-left: -8px;
margin-top: 35px;
z-index: 500;
}
.ui.black.button.toggle.opened{
margin-left: 0px;
}
```

**JQuery**

```
var sidebarStatus = 0;
$(document).on('click', '.ui.button.toggle', function() { 
    if(sidebarStatus === 0){
        sidebarStatus = 1;
        $(".ui.button.toggle").addClass("opened");                            
    } else if(sidebarStatus === 1){
        sidebarStatus = 0;
        $(".ui.button.toggle").removeClass("opened");
    }
});
```

Bye!